# require a Javascript module into another one webpack

Tags: javascript, module, webpack

I am in the process of building a JS library using the revealing module pattern with webpack and babel.

I have successfully been able to require two other modules into my main module, but when I created a constants module to be required into various other modules, it returns undefined.

To be more specific, my console inspector shows the file has been required and populates the data properly, but when my library attempts to use it on the next line, I get a typeError undefined.

```
var mic = (function(exports) {
        "use strict";

        var Const = require('constants.js'); // inspector shows it worked and populated data

        var status = Const.mic.status.idle; // JS module shows its undefined

        // public methods
        return {
            status: status
        };

     })();

    exports.mic = mic;
```

The problem I believe is that my constants.js is being required and populated by webpack after my 'mic' module. If this is the problem, how do I define the order which files should be bundled together with webpack?

Comment: How does `Const.mic` get populated? It seems like you have a circular dependency here. That is `constants.js` must `require('mic.js')` but `mic.js` also must `require(constants.js)`. Think of this as a chicken/egg problem. You need to remove the circular dependency. Maybe if you provide `constants.js` we can help the best way to do that.

Comment: Const.mic is not a module itself, 'mic' inside of Const is an object filled with hardcoded strings. Const is purely a file of organized hard coded strings, it does not require any module in it

Comment: Can you post the code for `constants.js`? Also, how can `constants.js` only be hard coded strings when you call `Const.mic.status.idle`?

Comment: Specifically show where `Const.mic` is defined.